# Extending form.is_valid()

Tags: django

I am learning Django, and i stumbled upon something that I need help with:

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1','password2')

    def password_matched(self):
        if self.data['password1'] != self.data['password2']:
            self.errors['password'] = 'Passwords do not match'
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super(UserForm,self).is_valid()
        password_matched = self.password_matched()
        if valid and password_matched:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
     #blah...
     user.set_password(user.password)
     # user.set_password(user.password1) doesn't work ! WHY!?
```

So basically, I am checking if `pw1 == pw2`,
after checking, I wish to set the user's password to password1.
I initially used the line `user.set_password(user.password1)` but it complained that User object doesn't have `password1`, yet it worked when I used `password`.

Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the [User model documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User), you'll see that it does not have a password1 field
**Edit**: I now see that you're using the standard User model from Django Authentication. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: It's the standard django auth User object

Comment: Your form has a field called password1, but not your User model.

Comment: Would this suffice? `user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get("password1"))` as per @karthikr 's answer

Comment: Yes, I believe so, you'll want to confirm by testing the code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be ideally using the `clean` method for this, and never be touching the `is_valid` method.

Something like this:

```
def clean(self):
    cd = self.cleaned_data

    password1 = cd.get("password1")
    password2 = cd.get("password2")

    if password1 != password2:
        #Or you might want to tie this validation to the password1 field
        raise ValidationError("Passwords did not match")



    return cd
```

Now, in the views,

```
def register(request):
   #blah...
   form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
   if request.method == "POST":
       if form.is_valid(): #This would call the clean method for you
           user = User.objects.create(...)
           user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get("password1"))
           user.save()
       else: #Form is invalid
           print form.errors #You have the error list here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I wish to return errors to the view, how would I do that?

Comment: You see the raise validationerror in the clean method ? That is giving you errors to the view. Checkthe edit