# unbound method is_valid() must be called with UserLoginForm instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Hello guys anyone with an idea help to solve this error, I am using Django framework to develop a simple application using Class based views.

Here is my View Codes:

```
class OpenLogin(FormView):
    template_name = 'signin.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class
        next_url = self.request.GET.get('next')
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

            obj = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if obj is not None:
                if obj.is_active():
                    login(self.request, obj)
                    if next_url is not None:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
                    else:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
                else:
                    messages.error(self.request, 'Error! sorry account is not active')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signin'))
            else:
                messages.error(self.request, 'Error!, sorry account is not found')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signin'))
        else:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Sorry! an error occurred, try again')
            context = {
                'title': 'Sign In',
                'next_url': next_url,
                'messages': messages.get_messages(self.request),
                'user': self.request.user,
                'form':form,
            }

            return context
```

And Here is my form Class:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=User._meta.get_field('email').max_length)
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=16, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super(UserLoginForm, self).is_valid()
        if not valid:
            return valid
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(
                Q(username=self.cleaned_data['username']) | Q(email=self.cleaned_data['username'])
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            self._errors['no_user'] = 'User does not exist'
            return False
        if not check_password(self.cleaned_data['password'], user.password):
            self._errors['invalid_password'] = 'Password is invalid'
            return False
        return True
```

After submitting the form I end up with the following error:

```
unbound method is_valid() must be called with UserLoginForm instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Where is my mistake? Help out

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227119/extending-form-is-valid) would help you understand why you should not extend is_valid method

Comment: Also there's no point in using a `FormView` if you totally replace it's `post()` method - you should hook into `form_valid()` and other hooks provided by `FormView`'s ancestors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here, but this is the one that's causing your immediate error:

```
 form = self.form_class
 ...
 if form.is_valid():
```

`self.form_class` is a reference to the class, not a form instance. You should construct a form instance based on your request, and validate that:

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST)
```

Comment: The comment about not using `FormView` if you're replacing `post` is sound - in my opinion the class-based views obscure too much of the logic for someone who's new to Django compared to purely functional views, but if you do want to use them you should expect to put some effort into figuring out what the smallest piece you can override to get your desired behavior is.